# How can I alias labels (using a query) in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-dashboard

I'm using Grafana v9.3.2.2 on Azure Grafana

I have a line chart with labels of an ID. I also have an SQL table in which the IDs are mapped to simple strings. I want to alias the IDs in the label to the strings from the SQL

I am trying to look for a transformation to do the conversion.

There is a transformation called “rename by regex”, but that will require me to hardcode for each case. Is there something similar with which I don't have to hardcode for each case.

There is something similar for variables - https://grafana.com/blog/2019/07/17/ask-us-anything-how-to-alias-dashboard-variables-in-grafana-in-sql/. But I don't see anything for transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 queries in the panel - one for data with IDs and seconds one for mapping ID to string. Then add transformation `Outer join` and use that field ID to join queries results into one result.

You may need to use also `Organize fields` transformation to rename, hide unwanted fields, so only right fields will be used in the label at the end.